# How to Get Category Name and Category Slug from Array to Create Permalinks

Tags: arrays, wordpress, categories

I want to Use Category array to Get Category Name and Slug so to make A Links in the form of https://my_site.com/category/categoryslug

the anchor links will be `<a href="https://my_site.com/category/categoryslug">categoryname</a>`

```
    function get_category_by_letter($letter){
    $args=array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'child_of' => 48,
    'hide_empty' => 0);

    $categories=get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) {

    $catname = $category->name;
    $first_letter = substr(strip_tags($catname), 0 , 1); // get the first     letter of the category
    if(strcasecmp($first_letter,$letter) != 0) continue; //if not the same letter then loop next NOTE: this is case insensitive comparison
    else{
      $cats[] = $category->term_id; //store category IDs in array
      $cats[] = $category->name;   
        }
    }
 return $cats;
}


   $the_let = $_GET['letter'];
   $cats = get_category_by_letter($the_let);
   var_dump($cats);
```

I Expect the Output to have Category names and slugs for links

Answer (score 0):

To get the category link use the `get_category_link()` with the $category->term_id as parameter to get the ID. Add the following code to your else statement as shown below:

```
if(strcasecmp($first_letter,$letter) != 0) continue; 
else{
  $cats[] = $category->term_id; //store category IDs in array
  $cats[] = $category->name;
  $cats[] = get_category_link($category->term_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by adding more information about how this answers OP's question.